# IOS Tab Bar Controller: resetting Tab B based on action in Tab A

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I'm interested to know conceptually how to reset tabs based on the actions in a "main tab" the app is a writing app in which one can work on multiple projects at a time.

The first tab will show a table view showing all the projects currently available, when one selects the a project, I would like all the other tabs to "reset" back to their home screen (some will have navigation where you can drill down)

Any thoughts appreciated, thainks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the controller with the table (in the "main tab"), you can access all of the tab bar controller's view controllers with self.tabBarController.viewControllers. You could loop through that array, and check if the object is a navigation controller -- if it is, call popToRootViewControllerAnimated: to go back to the initial content controller.

Answer (score 2):

To reset all tabs we can write the following code

```
- (void)resetAllTabs{
for (id controller in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {

    if ([controller isMemberOfClass:[UINavigationController class]]) {
        [controller popToRootViewControllerAnimated:NO];
    }
}
```